# Rally List all Features query

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to find a complete list of all Features available (I don't have many, just tinkering).  I've tried a number of different ways, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax for referencing the Features.

First attempt:

```
type: 'PortfolioItem/Feature'
key: 'Feature"
fetch: 'Name'
```

This resulted in an error.  I then tried:

```
type: 'hierarchicalrequirement'
key: 'features'
fetch: 'Name,Parent.Name'
```

Also an error.

I've listed the type as PortfolioItem, PortfolioItem/Feature, and Feature.  I've fetched for Name, formattedID, Parent.Name, parent.FormattedID, and maybe a few more. I can't seem to find where to search to just see a list of all of the features available. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

AppSDK 1.x isn't really setup to handle PortfolioItems with Dynamic Portfolio Item Types. At the very least, you'll need to update your API settings to use one compatible with dyna-types:

`rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.40");`

Even with this change in place, with AppSDK 1.x I usually have to query against type: 'PortfolioItem' and filter down to Features (or other types) client-side.

I'd recommend developing your app using [AppSDK 2](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/) which is currently in preview but is the supported Javascript SDK moving forward: